# How to save data written to txt file after refresh

Tags: php, html

Currently I have this PHP pieced together to write a 0 or 1 to a text file based on whether or not the input is checked upon submit. It works fine when I submit the form on the page, but as soon as I navigate to another page and return the text file is overwritten with 0 and does not save the last number (whether 0 or 1) written to the file.

PHP:

```
<?php
$file    = 'file.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
if (isset($_POST['mycheckbox'])) {
  $current = "1";
} else {
  $current = "0";
}
file_put_contents($file, $current);

$alerttext = 'alert!';

if ($current == 1) {
  print $alerttext;
  $switch = 'checked';
} else {
  $switch = '';
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <label class="switch db">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" class="switch db" 
               name="mycheckbox" value="Yes" <?php print $switch;?> 
               autocomplete="off"/>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Everytime that php is hit, it will write that file regardless of anything else that happened. You should wrap that file handler in something that checks if the form was actually submitted or not. Like use a `<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">` and then `if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {...` around the file stuff.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Pretty new to PHP. What would the full code snippet look like?

Comment: @IncredibleHat No luck. Text file is still 1. Using FF. Full syntax of your edit: 
    $current = ( !empty($_POST['mycheckbox']) ? "1" : "0" );

Comment: Figured it out. File permissions. Good to go! Thanks for your help  
@IncredibleHat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP:

```
<?php
$file    = 'file.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'form_was_submitted' ] ) ) {
$current = ( !empty( $_POST[ 'mycheckbox' ] ) ? "1" : "0" );
file_put_contents( $file, $current );
}
if ( $current == 1 ) {
$switch = 'checked';
} else {
    $switch = '';
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_was_submitted" value="1">
    <label class="switch db"><input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" class="switch db" name="mycheckbox" value="Yes" <?php print $switch;?> autocomplete="off"/><i></i></label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```